# MySQL: Create a query with multiple SELECTS using the result of the previous query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to retrieve the count of rows with a specific value, But this value depends on a query that must be done before using this result

The known variable is `adId`, for example `adId` is 32
So I want to get the value of the `requestFrom` where `adId = 32`

Easy: `$result = SELECT requestFrom FROM myTable WHERE adId = 32`

Then I get the count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE requestFrom = $result AND adId = $adId AND requestStatus = '1'
```

-
I want to do this (get the count) in only one query

```
+----+--------+-------------+------+--------+
| id | userId | requestFrom | adId | status |
+----+--------+-------------+------+--------+
|  1 |     23 |          58 |   32 |      1 |
|  2 |     23 |          65 |   37 |      0 |
|  3 |     76 |          27 |   73 |      1 |
|  4 |     29 |          58 |   29 |      1 |
```

Comment: What version of mySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Sub query to get this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable 
WHERE requestFrom = (select requestFrom from myTable where adId = $adId ) 
AND adId = $adId AND requestStatus = '1'
```

Comment: Prepared statements. prepared statements

Comment: Prepared statements.  The first three things to do  when using SQL with PHP.

Comment: @BillalBegueradj `$adId` is a php variable

Comment: Yes there are preparedstatements in PHP https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Indeed a prepared statement is best to use. However `$var = (int) $_POST/$_GET['xyz'];` would also work, given if it's always an integer.